# TypeError: this.attr is not a function on class hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, this

so I have a couple of images, and I want their src to display on another image when it hovers, and then reset back to its original when not hovering anymore. I figured I'd just use $(this), but I get

> TypeError: this.attr is not a function

```js
$(".card").hover(
function () {
    var image = $(this.attr('src'));
    $('.cardpreview').attr('src', $(this.attr('src')));
},

function () {
    $('.cardpreviw').attr('src', 'http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg');
});
```

```css
.card {
    width:120px;
    height:170px;
}
.cardpreview {
    width:480px;
    height:680px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
<img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
<img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
<img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
<img class="card" alt="card missing" src="http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg" />
<img class='cardpreview' alt='card missing' src='http://mtgimage.com/card/Craw Wurm.jpg' />
```

I figure the syntax is probably wrong, while the idea is good. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` is the native DOMElement. It has no `attr()` property. You need to convert it to a jQuery object by using `$(this)` to access jQuery properties and methods. Try this:

```
$(".card").hover(function () {
  $('.cardpreview').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
}, function () {
  $('.cardpreview').attr('src', 'http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg');
});
```

Note I also fixed the typo in the second `.cardpreview` selector.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a syntax error. To access the current element you have to use this syntax (for example to get a specific attribute of the element):

```
$(this).attr('src');
```

and not

```
$(this.attr('src'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second function call and try this

```
$(".card").on('hover',function(){
        var image = $(this).attr('src');
        $('.cardpreview').attr('src', $(this).attr('src');
        $('.cardpreviw').attr('src', 'http://mtgimage.com/card/cardback.jpg');
    });
```

Comment: Removing the second function changes the logic completely...?